# Process maker Document Upload - Error 404 sysworkflow was not found on this server

Tags: c#, rest, api, processmaker

While Uploading document on Processmaker through POSTMAN, I am able to upload the document but while accessing the same method via my C# code. I am getting an HTML page as response ERROR 404 /sysworkflow was not found on this server.

Answer (score 0):

Upon checking in the documentation, this is the endpoint: 
`/api/1.0/workflow/project/{prj_uid}/file-manager/{prf_uid}/upload`

maybe you are using this part of the endpoint that is making the ERROR 404 appear

```
/api/1.0/sysworkflow/project/{prj_uid}/file-manager/{prf_uid}/upload
```

Check this [documentation](http://wiki.processmaker.com/3.0/REST_API_Designer#UploadFile) out